# Position a map div within the containing parent div

Tags: css, mapbox

I am attempting to display a map div within another, parent div.

To be more specific, I would like the `<div id='map'></div>` to appear only within the div  `id="mapbox"`.  The problem that I am having is that the map is being displayed outside the containing div `id="mapbox"`.  There must be some CSS elsewhere on the page that is causing the map to display incorrectly.

```
<div class="g12" id="mapbox" style="display:none">        
<h1 style="padding-left:7px; padding-bottom:14px;">MapBox API</h1>  

<script src='http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v0.6.7/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v0.6.7/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />

<style>
    #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>

<div id='map'></div>

<script>
    mapbox.auto('map', 'examples.map-zr0njcqy');
</script>
```

Can someone explain how I might change the CSS so that my map div is styled to only stay within the containing parent div?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position absolute will make your element flow out of the normal document flow, so in order to prevent the element to flow out of the container box, you need to give `position: relative;` to the container element, this way, your absolute position div will be relative to the parent element

```
#mapbox {
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me in mapbox 2.1.5. I have to set a negative top value to get the map to appear that much in from the bottom of the parent element. Other strange behaviour includes that overflow: hidden on parent has no effect.